# Pointer to a map

Tags: c++, pointers

If I define a pointer-to-`map` like this:

```
map<int, string>* mappings;
```

`mappings` is a pointer. How should I use this pointer to operate the map?

Comment: BTW for valid use, assign `mappings` with a valid object address or `new map<int,string>`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the pointer just like you use any other pointer: dereference it to get to the object to which it points.

```
typedef std::map<int, string>::iterator it_t;

it_t   it1 = mappings->begin();   // (1)
it_t   it2 = (*mappings).begin(); // (2)

string str = (*mappings)[0];      // (3)
```

Remember that `a->b` is — mostly — equivalent to `(*a).b`, then have fun!

<sup>(Though this equivalence doesn't hold for access-by-index like `(*a)[b]`, for which you may not use the `->` syntax.)</sup>

Comment: You could use `a->operator[](b)`, but that's a bit ugly ;)

Comment: **Note:** My answer assumes that the pointer _actually_ points to an instance of `std::map<int, string>`; you did not show pointer initialisation in your question.

Comment: Why "mostly equivalent" ? `a->b` is not just a syntactic sugar for `(*a).b` ?

Comment: @Simon: This doesn't necessarily hold when operator overloads come into it.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: you're right, I missed that point. Thanks for the precision.

Comment: C++11 allows you to also do `mappings->at(0)`

Answer (score 5):

Not much difference except that you have to use `->` for accessing the `map` members. i.e.

```
mapping->begin() or mapping->end()
```

If you don't feel comfortable with that then you can **assign a reference** to that and use it as in the natural way:

```
map<int, string> &myMap = *mappings;  // 'myMap' works as an alias
                ^^^^^^^^
```

Use `myMap` as you generally use it. i.e.

```
myMap[2] = "2";
myMap.begin() or myMap.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

For instance:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::map<int, std::string> * mapping = new std::map<int, std::string>();
  (*mapping)[1] = "test";
  std::cout << (*mapping)[1] <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Since there is no size mentioned while allocating the map, how is memory allocated for the first entry? Won't we have to allocate memory for every entry added to the map?

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of ["at"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) function in c++ 11, you can use `mappings->at(key)` instead of `(*mapping)[key]`.

Keep in mind that this api will throw `out_of_range` exception if the key is not already available in the map.

Answer (score 0):

another nice way of using pointers, which I like is calling mappings->(and the function you want to call)

Comment: I thought he meant the dereferencing by calling (*mappings) to get the value, but now that he added the code I see he covered both bases :)

Answer (score -3):

Well, STL is designed to reduce the complexity of pointer handling..so better approach is to use stl::iterator.. try to avoid pointers :-/

Comment: There is no such thing as `stl::iterator` and, even if there were, it would not function as a pointer-to-map.